# How to modify dict with one of its key

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the best method to modify dict in following scenario

```
d = {
'a' : {
        'a1': 1,
        'a2': 1,
        'a3': 8
      }
}
```

I want to modify it to

```
d = {
'a' : {
        'a3': 8
      }
}
```

The only way I can think of is

```
store_a3 = d['a']['a3']
d['a'] = store_a3
```

or deleting all other keys like.

Is there any way by which we can directly replace all other key by `a3`. It may sound dump. But I am an absolute beginner.

```
# This is incorrect but I was looking for this type of implementation
d['a'] = #someassignment which will be equal to {'a3' : 8}
```

Note: I know the key value which needs to be assigned

Comment: What's the logic? Just make sub-dict to have single specific key-value pair?

Comment: `d['a'] = {'a3': d['a']['a3']}`…?

Comment: @Chris I am getting a config dict as input which will be sent as dict to logging module. So I have to remove all unrequired keys.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it Pythonic I'd use a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
d['a'] = {k: v for k, v in d['a'].items() if k == 'a3'}
```

Where `k` stands for key and `v` for value.

Comment: Comprehension in this case would create unnecessary loop; it will have to iterate all the keys and therefore loses advantage of `dict`